# Date field not working properly in grails

Tags: date, grails, groovy, grails-orm, shiro

I have a `lastLogin` field in my `User` domain class with type `Date`. I use it to track the last login date with time. When a user logs in successfully I change this field value as under,

```
someUser.lastLogin = new Date()
 someUser.save()
```

When I view that user in list the lastLogin value looks like this `2014-38-12 04:38:40` i.e the `month` in the `date` is replaced by the `time`.  Every time I try, this occurs. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you specified a Date format (for when you output the date) like:

```
'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss'
```

That is incorrect, you need:

```
'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
```

(note: [capital M for Month](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html))